# Eevee - Viewport Render image vs F12 rendering (speed)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, optimization

I wonder why Eevee renders slowly when pressing F12, while viewport rendering does the same exact picture (down to the pixel) but takes less than a second.
Where are these seconds lost ? What kind of computation is the CPU-GPU doing that makes me wait to finally display the same picture as "viewport render" ?
It's annoying because I would like to use the compositor (not compatible with viewport rendering) while keeping fast render times (for a still image, 1 second vs 15 is not an issue, but for animations it's more a problem).